# Creating FORM programetically - .submit won't activate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The form I created will not activate .submit. There are no ids or names = 'submit'.
The 'Go Back' button functions as coded. Program goes back to calling page. **The 'Update' input type=submit does nothing.** I don't know how to fix this as *web developer tools* doesn't show a hint of what's wrong.

[The image is of the functioning Form '#revForm']

```
$(function () {
    
    var form_str="";
    var fields=<?php echo json_encode($fields); ?>;
    var cfields=<?php echo json_encode($capFields); ?>;
    var qdata=<?php echo json_encode($qdata); ?>;


    $("#returnvalbox").show();

    $(".formcontainer").append("<form id='revForm' name='revForm' method='post' action='#'>");

    var i=0;

    Object.keys(qdata).forEach(key => {  // create the form body

        if (key=="id") {   // you can't edit the id
            form_str="<label for='"+key+"'>"+cfields[i++]+" </label>";
            form_str+="<input  type='text' class='body' ";
            form_str+="id='"+key+"'name='"+key+"' value='"+qdata[key]+"' readonly  ><br>";  
        }else {
            form_str="<label for='"+key+"'>"+cfields[i++]+" </label>";
            form_str+="<input  type='text' class='hov body' ";
            form_str+="id='"+key+"'name='"+key+"' value='"+qdata[key]+"'><br>"; 
        } 


    $(".formcontainer").append(form_str);

    }); //Object.keys
    
    $(".formcontainer").append("<br><input  type='submit' class='cbut hov' value='Update'>")
                    .append("&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type='button' class='cbut hov' id='bak'>Go Back</button><p></p>");
    $(".formcontainer").append("</form>");
                
    $("#revForm").submit(function(event) {  
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("submitted Line 142");  **<<============= this does nothing !**
    }) // submit 
            
}) // ready
```

Comment: Your append process is wrong. You can't append an opening tag then some other elements and then a  closing tag and expect the other elements to be inside the form. What is basically happening is the form gets appended to the container then the elements get appended to the container and not the form. Thus the submit button is not inside the form. You can confirm this by inspecting the resultant DOM in browser dev tools elements inspector

Comment: Thanks VERY much mulquin. I've been going over & over this and missed it. Works fine once I .appended() to #revForm. R